# v-model with same selected object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a array with objects:

```
array = [{id: 1, value: 0},{id: 2, value: 0},{id: 3, value: 0},{id: 4, value: 0}]
```

after a quick selection with my UI I have a selected object array

```
selectedArray = [{id: 1, value: 0},{id: 2, value: 0},{id: 1, value: 0}]
```

You can not I push 2 time the id:1, it's necessary for my timeline.

so now I make a v-for on it

```
<div v-for="item in selectedArray">
<input type="number" v-model="item.value">
</div>
```

But If I change the value of the first item , the third change too.

How can I fix this

Comment: But the first and the third are the same value ? Or they are 2 different variable with same id ?

Comment: they are the same object but I need to change their value independently

Comment: You can't modify the structure such that the third value is a copy and is initialized with the first value (and so become an other id) ?

Comment: I just need to keep the same id for the both same object

Comment: Ok but if they are the same object, they will share their value too :/

Comment: it's the same object but not at same index in array, they're not solution ?

Comment: I will answer you sincerely: I don't know at all. I would have told you no, but I can't prove otherwise.

Comment: How you manipulate the first item??

Answer (score 1):

You can add key attribute to each item.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in selectedArray" :key="index">
<input type="number" v-model="item.value">
</div>
```